# How to save UIDatePicker Date and print it back out?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker on my ViewController, and When I click the save button,  I want it to save the date to a variable, allowing me to print the content of the variable, which should be the date that it was set.

I have a model(Class) to save all info on my ViewController (UiTextField text, etc...), I am just not sure how to save a date from the DatePicker and print it out.  Can anyone help me figure how to make it work?

This is my first app(Besides Hello World)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDate* pickerDate = picker.date;
NSLog(pickerDate); // or NSLog(@"Date: %@", pickerDate);
```

[UIDatePicker Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)

Comment: Would you like example code of other types of format for the date to be converted to? maybe numbers for the year/month/day or a string value?

Comment: How to convert to a string value would be great.

Comment: Also, is it a similar way to save the state of a UISwitch? [On/Off]

Comment: the actual string can be gotten from the pickerDate.description, which is what is defaulted print out when you try to print out the pickerDate in the log, but if you would like some specific format of a date that could be a really lengthy conversation and i would rather just point you to NSDateFormatter class reference

Answer (score 0):

A'sa Dickens already showed how to get a date from your date picker. An NSDate object is a property list object, so it can be written to a plist or user defaults directly. NSDate also conforms to NSCoding, so you can add NSDate objects to archives.

You can also convert an NSDate to a double using the NSDate instance method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, and convert from a double to a date using the NSDate class method dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.